# CSS: Display-Bug

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am programming a new homepage of my company with TYPO3 ( and the Bootstrap 3 package ) and I have a big problem.

There is a bug in the mobile navigation. It looks like this in HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <p>1</p>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <p>1.1</p>
  <p>1.2</p>
  <p>1.3</p>
  <p>1.4</p>
 </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <p>1</p>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <p>1.1</p>
  <p>1.2</p>
  <p>1.3</p>
  <p>1.4</p>
 </ul>
</li>
```

The < ul > is shown if the < li > is clicked. Then the class of the < li > is "dropdown open". If u click again then the class is "dropdown" again and the < ul > isnt displayed.

The dropdown menu isn't displayed the same in desptop-view and mobile-view. But if we are on mobile and want to click the dropdon away, the desktop dropdown appears.

I tryed this code to fix this:

```
.dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  display: none !important;
}
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block !important;
}
```

But it failed. As I injected this code while Debug with Chrome, it does work.

What did I wrong?

Comment: Start here — http://validator.w3.org/nu/ — you have obvious, machine detectable, errors.

Comment: Fix your broken HTML. `ul` can not have `p` as children.

Comment: i used p to demonstrate my problem to u

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media` queries to work out which dropdown menu to display on which screen size

Check this page out for tutorial: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

```css
   .dropdown.desktop > .dropdown-menu {
 display: none;    }    .dropdown.desktop.open > .dropdown-menu {
 display: block;    }
   .dropdown.mobile > .dropdown-menu, .mobile {
 display: none;    }
   @media screen and (max-width : 640px) {
 .dropdown.mobile > .dropdown-menu {
   display: none;
 }
 .dropdown.mobile.open > .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
 }    }
   @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .dropdown.mobile > .dropdown-menu {
   display: none;
 }
 .dropdown.mobile.open > .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
 }    }
```

```html
   <ul class="dropdown desktop open">
<li>1</li>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li>1.1</li>
 <li>1.2</li>
 <li>1.3</li>
 <li>1.4</li>
</ul>    </ul>    <ul class="dropdown mobile">
<li>1</li>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li>1.1</li>
 <li>1.2</li>
 <li>1.3</li>
 <li>1.4</li>
</ul>    </ul>
```